# Is landing in water worse than landing in trees when free-falling?

Tags: mortality, survival

[This popular YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dy5xLVx2NGY) which is about surviving when jumping from a plane with the parachute failing says at 1:03:

> You're looking for 3 things: Swamps, snow, trees. Your best chance of surviving is to land in one of those 3. Just stay away from water. Whatever you do, **don't land in the water**!

With

> (You'll die.)

being written on the screen.

I wasn't able to find much about this on the internet but it seems straight-forward that landing in a swamp or in deep snow is better than landing in water. But is landing in trees better than landing in water?

Nicholas Alkemade landed in trees and survived. I don't know whether anyone else did and didn't find anything regarding water.

1. Is it possible to survive a free fall from great hight when landing in water?
2. Does landing in trees increase your chances of survival as compared to landing in water?
3. Have people survived landing in a swamp after freely falling from great heights?

Kind of related question (regarding drowning when landing in water; but I suppose also relevant when landing in a swamp or in snow): Are survivors of such falls generally conscious shortly after impact?

Comment: I wonder whether the sample sizes are large enough to be able to show a statistically significant difference.  Numbers 1 and 3 are asking for anecdotal evidence which is not likely to help much with the question.

Comment: Considering that jumping from bridges is a fairly common method of committing suicide, so much so that some bridges have suicide prevention hotline phone numbers on them, I am not at all skeptical of this claim.

Comment: @NateEldredge Questions 1 and 3 can be answered by stating a single event. They are questions about existence. I'm not asking for "anecdotal evidence" (I think this qualifies as an oxymoron). Existence can be demonstrated using a single example. That's the nature of questions about existence.

Comment: As comment, since no references:  When falling from a great height, humans reach a velocity where aerodynamic drag matches the force of gravity: this is the terminal velocity, and is reached after 60 m or so of falling. The terminal velocity for a person is >200 km/h; hitting a body of water perpendicularly at that speed would be uniformly fatal, since at that speed given the viscosity of water the impact is essentially the same as hitting a cement floor.  People have (rarely) survived by hitting trees and hitting snowy slopes; don't know about swamps (maybe swamp grass cushions you?)

Comment: @phoog I always figured people jump onto land, not onto water. Large bridges typically span an entire valley with plenty of land, not just a river.

Comment: @antlersoft I doubt the grass on swamps does anything significant. Instead, I figured that what (possibly) kills you when you hit water is not the acceleration you experience due to its drag (which depends on its viscosity) as you claim but the force you experience on impact due to surface tension. A swamp has way higher viscosity than plain water but hardly any surface tension. If what you wrote was true, it'd mean that swamps are even deadlier than water.

Comment: @UTF-8 look up some news articles and you'll see that the bodies are generally retrieved from the water.

Comment: @UTF-8: Right, I agree you can validly ask about existence.  But it's unhelpful for answering the larger question about whether landing in the water carries a significant chance of survival.  If you find an example of someone who lived, you do know the chance is larger than zero, but without knowing the number who died, you can't distinguish between 100% and 0.0000001%.  If you don't find an example, you don't know whether it's because the survival rate is 0%, or whether there is just inadequate reporting.

Comment: @phoog: On the one hand, people who jump from bridges into the water do occasionally survive.  On the other hand, bridges are usually not high enough for terminal velocity to be attained.  I don't think anyone doubts that falling into water is *sometimes* fatal; the claim is basically that it is *invariably* fatal.

Comment: @NateEldredge Exactly. Since I don't expect the sample size to be large enough to draw any real conclusions from it, I'm content with knowing whether such landings are invariably fatal.

Comment: The Golden Gate Bridge is ~220 feet off the water (~80MPH impact) and while falling / jumping is not _invariably_ fatal (https://www.modernluxury.com/san-francisco/story/kevin-hines-still-alive), the the fatality rate is 98% (Wikipedia). Terminal velocity takes ~1500 feet, but OTOH the question relates to a person striving to survive, so they might adopt the skydiving "modified frog position" in which you drop at ~120MPH. But OTOH you definitely don't want to _land_ flat, so you probably need to tuck into a foot-first impact (I'd guess), which means you'd be going somewhat faster than 120.

Comment: Let's clean this up and re-open. Q1: "Is it possible" is largely a theoretical question. "Has it ever happened" is better, but doesn't match the claim. Q2: Matches the claim, but we all seem to agree there isn't going to be any evidence. It's valid to have this sit open and unanswerable, but you seem to want more. Q3: Separate question, with a simple answer if you want to try that one alone.

Comment: @antlersoft - What Larry OBrien said -- terminal velocity is highly dependent on the body's alignment.  I recall reading once that the velocity could be reduced to less than 100mph by falling spread-eagle.  But, as Larry says, the trick is to then shift to a foot-first alignment before entering the water.

Comment: IIRC random sources I don't recall from my past, generally hitting water is quite dangerous because *physics*. So, i'm not at all surprised if this claim is true.

Comment: @Oddthinking Thank you for your suggestions. I now split the question up into 3 easier-to-answer questions: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/39852/is-it-possible-to-survive-landing-in-water-when-free-falling https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/39851/have-people-survived-landing-in-trees-when-free-falling https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/39850/have-people-survived-landing-in-swamps-when-free-falling

Comment: @UTF-8: and they seem to be getting quality answers. Yay.